# python string interpolation syntax error

Tags: python, string-interpolation

I am playing with the string interpolation and I keep getting the following and don't understand why I keep getting invalid syntax

```
>>> import time
>>> today = time.strftime("%A")
>>> print "Today is %s." % today
File "<ipython-input-3-c488ebb957ac>", line 1
print "Today is %s." % today
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: no this is Python 2.7

Comment: @user2757400 - Can you run `import sys; print sys.version` in *the same interpreter session*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're inadvertently invoking a Python3 interpreter.  Try `print("Today is %s." % today)`. (`print()` as a function rather than the old `print` as a statement.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 — which you must be using here considering your code is valid Python 2 —, `print` is a function, and must therefore be called with parentheses:

```
print("Today is %s." % today)
```

Note that if you're running Python 2, then you could have enabled this behavior with the following command (did you do any interpreter customizations?):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

---

Note that the Python version you're running is displayed when you startup the interpreter. You can also run `python --version` from your command line to see it.